# fatal error Call to a member function getReadConnection() pn boolean on my localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.2.2

I AM GETTING THIS on going to my backend or front end on `magento 1.9.2.2`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on boolean
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\shokart\includes\src__default.php on line 32629

I dont know what to do as i am new to magento

Comment: Could you try to disable compilation ? Under System > Tools > Compilation

Comment: What's at line 32696?

Answer (score 1):

Open `include/config.php`. and add php comment `#` all lines there.

Comment: thnks now its working

Comment: You can accept then! it will help others

Answer (score 0):

By the way - windows does not work with Magento well. I was struggling with it whole week and Virtual Box with LAMP worked for me much better.